# How can I have a slash-separated varidic path parameter with go_router?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

In my application, I have plugins. Each plugin has a user interface, which can be accessed through a [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) route with a UUID path parameter (`/plugin/:uuid`).

For example, this is one such path:
`/plugin/d2673356-2904-42ff-a196-3388779c386b`.

Some plugins, however, can host child plugins of their own. I would like to make these accessible using the same route.
A plugin nested two levels deep, for example, may be found at:
`/plugin/d2673356-2904-42ff-a196-3388779c386b/ec1e8596-6114-4ece-90fc-912f3f293dfe/8a12bab3-5654-441d-8070-61715d4188c6`

How can I change my route (from `/plugin/:uuid`) to accept such a format? I would like to end up with an ordered `List` containing each UUID.